# Call Fastlane action (GradleAction) from random ruby script

Tags: ruby, fastlane

My question is very simple, how can I call some Fastlane actions directly from ruby scripts? I want to do something like below, if possible.

```
    require 'fastlane'
    class MyRunner
      def run
        Fastlane::Actions::GradleAction.run( {
                                         task: ":assemble",
                                         build_type: 'Release',
                                         properties: {
                                             'versionCode' => 1,
                                             'versionName' => '1.0.0'
                                         }
                                     })
      end
    end
```

I have tried with `Fastlane::Runner.new.execute("gradle")` but it didn't work.

NOTE: I tried running this with no Fastfile around